# # Error: ImportError: No module named samples.lightIntensity #

Tags: python, module, maya

It's my script:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def changeLightIntensity(percentage=1.0):
    """
    Changes the intensity of each light the scene by percentage.

    Parameters:
        percentage - Percentage to change each light's intensity. Default value is 1.

    Returns:
        Nothing.
    """
    #The is command is the list command. It is used to list various nodes
    #in the  current scene. You can also use it to list selected nodes.
    lightInScene = cmds.ls(type='light')

    #If there are no lights in the scene, there is no point running this script
    if not lightInScene:
        raise RunTimeError, 'There are no lights in the scene!'

    #Loop through each light
    for light in lightInScene:
        #The getAttr command is used to get attribute values of a node
        currentIntensity = cmds.getAttr('%s.intensity' % light)
        #Calculate a new intensity
        newIntensity = currentIntensity * percentage
        #Change the lights intensity to the new intensity
        cmds.setAttr('%s.intensity' % light, newIntensity)
        #Report to the user what we just did
        print 'Changed the intensity of light %s from %.3f to %.3f' % (light, currentIntensity, newIntensity)


import samples.lightIntensity as lightIntensity
lightIntensity.changelightIntensity(1.2)
```

My error's:

> ImportError: No module named samples.lightIntensity

What's the problem? Can I do to this? What's the solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're following [this](http://www.chadvernon.com/blog/resources/python-scripting-for-maya-artists/python-in-maya/) tutorial. What you've misunderstood is that the last two lines in your code sample are not supposed to be part of the script, but they are meant to run the previous code in the interpreter. If you take another look at the tutorial, you'll see that there's a header above the main code sample saying **lightIntensity.py**, while the second, smaller code sample is preceded by *"To run this script, in the script editor type..."*

So, this:

```
import samples.lightIntensity as lightIntensity
lightIntensity.changelightIntensity(1.2)
```

should not be in your file in that form.

There are two things you could do. Both should solve the problem and allow you to run the code, though I would prefer the second for ease of use.

1. Save the code without the last two lines as `lightIntensity.py`, and in the python shell, (start python, on the command line, IDLE, whatever you're using), and after the prompt, type `import lightIntensity` to import your script, and `lightIntensity.changelightIntensity(1.2)` to call the function in the script.
2. Alternatively, you can fix the script so that it runs without trying to import itself. To do so, remove the `import` line and change the last line to `changelightIntensity(1.2)`

Comment: I missed something again.

Because I saved the script as lightIntensity.py then I ran the two lines:

import samples.lightIntensity as lightIntensity
lightIntensity.changelightIntensity(1.2)



And I got the error: ImportError: No module named samples.lightIntensity

What went wrong (again) ?

Comment: Ah, right. Actually, `import samples.lightIntensity` would only work if lightIntensity.py is in a package called `samples`. Just do `import lightIntensity` instead.